# Calculating file name with field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

Is it possible to calculate the file name in an attribute table?

My shapefile has a name like "cities.shp". In this shapefile I want to have a attribute "cities").

Comment: Can you please clarify 'calculating file name'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for that stupid question! I did find an very easy way to do what I aked in this thread. Just use the QGis processing tool and the SAGA "merge vector layers" tool. The merged shape file has a column (called "Layer") filled with the shape file names.

Comment: Brilliant! Glad you got it sorted, remember to accept your answer after 2 days of posting (and your question wasn't stupid at all buddy!)

Comment: OK! Hope I'll remember bud!

Answer (score 5):

You can copy the following script to your QGIS (*Processing Toolbox* > *Scripts* > *Tools* > *Create new script*). This script takes shapefiles from one folder, uses the Field Calculator algorithm to add the filename as an attribute (with *Null* values but you can edit this to another expression) and outputs the shapefiles into another folder:

```
##Test=name

import os
import glob
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

#   Change to match your folder path for shapefiles
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

def run():

#   Set directory and search for all shapefiles then run algorithm
    os.chdir(path_dir + "Shapefiles\\")
    for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"): 

        processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", fname, fname, 2, 99, 0, True, 'NULL' , path_res  + "/"+ fname)

#   Paths of the shapefiles in the Result folder with list comprehension
    output = [shp for shp in glob.glob(path_res + "*.shp")]

run()
```

There are ways to write attributes to existing shapefiles but I don't have that knowledge yet. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this but withoud success...it might be my fault, because I'm a rookie in writing scripts. What I did is I created a new script and copied your script. On my desktop I created a folder "Test" and then "Test\Shapefiles". After starting the script (it is running without errors) nothing happens and the log says "Algorithm Test starting...

Algorithm Test finished"

Comment: OK! Now it worked but not really with the result I need. Now I have the shape-name as column name. But I need to have the name of the shape inside the column as an attribute.

Comment: I've tried to update the script above to write the filename into the new field created by the field calculator by altering the inputs like this, using fname as the formula: 

      processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", fname, 'Filename', 2, 50, 0, True, fname , path_res  + "/"+ fname)

However, when I run it it correctly creates the 'Filename' field but it deletes all of the features in the shapefile.  I assume fname isn't a suitable input, can anyone suggest anything else?

(I ask only because the SAGA tools on Mac OSX are currently broken)

Comment: @EdRollason - To clarify, you want to have the name of the file as values in a column called `Filename`? If so, try adding this extra line after the `for` statement: `formula = "'" + fname + "'"`. FYI on either side, it's a single quote surrounded by double quotes. Then type `formula` as the...formula: `processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", fname, 'Filename', 2, 50, 0, True, formula, path_res + "/"+ fname)`. This should give you the filename as values whilst retaining all the features.

Comment: @EdRollason - Awesome buddy, glad it worked :)

Comment: Hi Joseph - is it possible to trim the fname to just the first two characters? thanks

Comment: @EdRollason - Will have to get back to you on this one. You can always [ask](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question with the script you use if you need an answer fairly quickly.

Comment: No bother, just thought I'd ask in case you knew off the top of your head!

Comment: Which `fname` do you want to trim? The one for the attributes, or the output filename or both?

Answer (score 2):

From your comment I would assume that you just want to add a new field?

Open the attribute table of the file, start an edit session, and then use this button:

[image]

In your case you would have to opt for *Text*:

[image]

Comment: To add a columb is not the problem. The comprtition is to put the name of the layer into the column. At least I want to do this witch the processing batch tool for more than just 2 files.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a simple way, in the field calculator you can use layer_properties (in the 'MAP  Layers' group) with the 'path' property as well as the base_file_name function to strip out just the filename (without extension)

Example:
if you have a layer called 'Layer Name' and it's source file was c:\my directories\myShapeFile.shp, then the following expression will give you 'myShapeFile'

base_file_name( layer_property('Layer Name','path'))