# Load multiple files from folder for further processing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm working on a processing model and I'm looking for a possibility to load multiple shape-files from an Input-folder for further processing (first clip them all to a certain extend, then assign them to variables for further processes etc.) with a python script.

The problem is that the number of files in the Input-folder can vary from model-run to model-run. So far, the user has to define a certain number of shapefiles as Input.

Any Ideas about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like the following in your script which finds all shapefiles in a selected folder and for each shapefile, applies a processing function:

```
##Example=name
##Select_folder=Folder

import glob

for layers in glob.glob( Select_folder + "/" + "*.shp" ):
    # Do some processing
```

---

**EDIT**:

In response to the comments, you can process and output individual shapefiles by using similar code below (I used the buffer algorithm as an example):

```
##Example=name
##Select_directory=Folder
##Save_results=Folder

import glob, os, processing

os.chdir(Select_directory)
for layers in glob.glob( "*.shp" ):
    processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", layers, 10, 10, False, Save_results + "/" + layers)
```

Comment: Looks good, I will try it as soon as I could. Thanks a lot so far!

Comment: @Miron - Most welcome, hope it will help :)

Comment: do you know (or does someone know) how to save the output as separated files? Let’s say my folder contains four shape files I want to convert to raster, how do I save each single one?

Comment: @Miron - I think I gave an answer which did something similar [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132919/calculating-file-name-with-field-calculator). The key parts are assigning the paths of the shapefiles and results, seach for the shapefiles using `glob.glob()`, then add the path of the result in the output algorithm.

Comment: @Miron - See my edited post :)